# Who are the narrators in Game of Thrones Conquest & Rebellion: An Animated History of the Seven Kingdoms?

Tags: game-of-thrones, animation

In the ***Game of Thrones Conquest & Rebellion: An Animated History of the Seven Kingdoms*** there are several narrators for each episodes. And I think all of them are related to Game of Thrones series, because they talk about the characters as their family.

So who are the narrators in Game of Thrones Conquest & Rebellion: An Animated History of the Seven Kingdoms ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Nerdist - Game Of Thrones Animated Short Explains The Conquests Of Westeros](https://nerdist.com/game-of-thrones-animated-short-film-explains-the-conquests-of-westeros/)

> It is narrated by Viserys (Daenerys’s brother who died in season one
>   but doesn’t seem to know that<sup>[1]</sup>), Varys, Euron Greyjoy, Jaime Lannister,
>   Sansa Stark, and Petyr Bearish.

& though I haven't seen it yet, I presume that this means it's portrayed as the characters doing the narration, rather than the actors who play those characters.

*Edit:* Having just watched it... the entire cast is listed in the opening minute & indeed the narration is by the characters, as opposed to the actors.

<sup>[1]</sup> Of course, neither Viserys nor any of the other characters at this point in time know of the events to come, from Season 1 of the TV show. It is all set in the years leading up to when the show starts.

Answer (score 2):

> Cast members **Pilou Asbæk (Euron Greyjoy), Nikolaj Coster-Waldau (Jaime Lannister), Aidan Gillen (Littlefinger), Conleth Hill (Varys), Harry Lloyd (Viserys Targaryen) and Sophie Turner (Sansa Stark)** team up to narrate  the animated telling of Aegon Targaryen’s attempts to conquer the Seven Kingdoms, written by show writer Dave Hill.
>
> Referred from http://collider.com/game-of-thrones-animated-history-seven-kingdoms/